# How can i make my Discord Bot deleting all Channels in a server

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.js

i've made a Discord Bot, it can delete ONE Channel, but i want it to delete ALL Text and Voice Channels in a Server, how can i do this, using VSC as IDE with Node.js (I have installed discord.js too)

My Script looks like this:

[this is the link to a photo of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3480M.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please copy and paste your code to here by editing your question so that it's easier for us to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Please note that what you are asking violates the Discord API TOS. You should only perform this action if it is on your own, closed server.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the channels of the server like this:

```
 const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { prefix, token} = require('./config.json');
console.log('charging')
client.once('Loading...', () => {
    console.log('Loading...');
});
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === `${prefix}lol`) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 13000; i++) {
            message.channel.send('<@632899988011220992>')
            ;
        }
    } else if (message.content === `${prefix}test`) {
        const channels = message.guild.channels;
channels.forEach( channel => {  channel.delete(); })
        
}; })

        

client.login(token)
```

Comment: where must i paste this? Under what line of code?

Comment: when i paste it under "else if (message.content === `${prefix}test`) {"               it dont work

Comment: Ok this is the right place can you send me your code + the error ?

Comment: but only as a picture bcz when i want to add a comment an then pste my code it says "too long" lol

Comment: Your else if is not right you have to add a } at the end of the code

Comment: I corrected your code in my answer just copy paste

Comment: It’s strange is it the same line of code ?

Comment: how do u mean this?

Comment: this one that i posted as "error" is the error i get

Comment: maybe i must made the "message" part as a new function?

Comment: whait a min pls

Comment: I don’t think so but the error is not the code search on stackoverflow message is not defined discord.js